# What does bind() and rebind() in jQuery do that is different the regular onclick?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the difference between

```
function bind() {$('#content').click(function(){});}
```

and

```
function rebind() {$('#content').click(function(){});}
```

and simple

```
$('#content').click(function(){});
```

Or in other words - why do I need to use `bind()` if I simply want to attach simple click event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a common

```
function func(){ alert('woo!'); }
```

I think you might've seen something that mentions

```
$('#content').bind('click', func);
```

is the same as

```
$('#content').click(func);
```

Is that what you mean/saw?

Answer (score 5):

The advantage of the form .bind() is that you can target multiple events:

```
$("#content").bind("click dblclick focus", function() {
    doSomethingForAllCases();
});
```

Comment: This is a great point (btw, you don't need to wrap in an anonymous function here, you can just put a reference to `doSomethingForAllCases`).

Answer (score 4):

What you've pasted are not jQuery functions, they're just functions in your own code. They both do exactly the same thing, as evidenced by the function bodies being identical.

Comment: Function bodies being identical don't * necessarily* mean they're exactly the same.  Technically their name properties and addresses are different, but now we're just splitting hairs, :P (`bind.name !== rebind.name`, `bind !== rebind`).

Comment: @Dan: true that! The identical function bodies *in this specific case* tells us that the functions do exactly the same thing, but I'll grant that identical bodies per se doesn't *have to* mean that two functions are doing the exact same thing. It should also be noted that somewhere down the line, perhaps `rebind` is redefined, but `bind` isn't, so we can't know for sure that even in this specific case it would be safe to change all usages of `rebind` to use `bind` and then remove `rebind`.

Comment: Except that two different function bodies have different scope, i.e. `function a() { this.something = false; }` and `.call({hellz: 'yeah'});` will have different results.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to use `bind` for default events like click, onMouse etc..

> Bind is useful when you are customizing some events and then
>   attaching that event to an element or     if you want to attach
>   multiple events at a time.
>
> the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to .bind() occurs

refer - [this](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)